# 'grep' command not highlighting User input word in the Search result

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, grep, egrep

I am trying to write shell script as below to search user inputted word and highlight the word in the search result -

## User input:

echo -n -e "What you wanna search:"
read userinput

## Save the search result in a file

egrep "$input" /var/log/auth.log > result.txt

## Display the result column wise with highlighted user input value

column -t result.txt | grep '$userinput' --> (this is not working. It's not highlighted the word)

For example: I am looking for 'root' user in the search result and I want to highlight the 'root' word being highlighted but it's not working.

$ column -t result.txt | grep -n 'root' *--> This is working*
$ column -t result.txt | grep -n '$userinput' **--> This is not working**

Any idea what's I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `--color=always` to your grep command.  For instance:

```
column -t result.txt | grep --color=always '$userinput'
```

When you call `grep` interactively, it uses color by default. But when you call it in a shell script, it doesn't use color, so you need to force it with `--color=always`

Comment: Just awesome Dave. d -- it is working, great and thanks